# Get top 5 recent post by taxonomy term

Tags: theming

I am new to Drupal and I have started overriding Twig files in Drupal 8. I have a requirement where I want other top 5 posts by taxonomy term.

Suppose I have a category as JavaScript. And I am on the node where I am displaying a post on JavaScript. On the same page I need other posts on JavaScript.

I have looked for twig file `theme/templates/content/node--article.html.twig` and tried to override it.

I have even tried to debug the node using `kint` tool. I have looked for my requirements in node and content variable.

```
{{ kint(node) }}
{{ kint(content) }}
```

But no success. I need suggestion where can I can other posts of same category in twig file. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for Views, no?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you say:

> I have started overwriting Twig files in Drupal 8.

I hope you mean "overriding" Twig files.

Rule #1: *Don't hack core.*

Secondly, as leymannx suggests in the comment above, this is better accomplished using Views rather than in a Twig template.

Comment: Yes. Updated my question. Yup I found a solution to create a view and render it in twig template using twig tweak plugin.